# How do i fix the grouping factor error in wilcox test?

Tags: r, statistics, tidyverse, analysis, t-test

I am new to R
I am trying to run non-parametric wilcox test
Looking for in difference in BMI(continuous numeric variable) with general health categories(Good, Very good, Excellent, Fair, Poor)

```
#run this code
wilcox.test(bmi~genhealth, data=BmiGTib,conf.int=T)
```

getting this error
Error in wilcox.test.formula(bmi ~ genhealth, data = BmiGTib, conf.int = T) :
grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels

need help, thank you

Comment: If you split BMI into "BMI high" and "BMI normal" this approach might work, or perhaps a Kruskal-Wallis test would be more appropriate? Regardless, this is not [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for stackoverflow and is better suited to https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Kruskal Wallis test worked for me, Thank you